# pyautogui error with DISPLAY, when python script is called from php

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm trying to use pyautogui module. Everything works as expected if I run the script from the console. When I try to execute python script from php (shell_exec) I get the following error in apache2 error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 160, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

Here is my python scipt:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import pyautogui
import sys

print("Trying to get info")
pyautogui.click(3500,102,1)
```

And here is php:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python3 test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `xhost +` and exporting the `DISPLAY` variable in python manually by something like `os.environ['DISPLAY']=:1` where :1 is the content of your DISPLAY variable.